# Weird mercurial Graph

Tags: graph, mercurial

Im trying to interpret a mercurial repository and more specific its Graph. Most of what happened is clear to me, but there are two places, where I need some help understanding what happened.

**Problem A: "mq"**

```
o  changeset:   93:b0aa6f2898b6
|  parent:      91:88cca7c8f32e
|  user:        test <test@gmail.com>
|  date:        Tue Feb 19 13:36:00 2019 +0100
|  summary:     some message
|
| o  changeset:   92:0aff2e92ec57
|/   user:        test <test@gmail.com>
|    date:        Tue Feb 12 18:10:10 2019 +0100
|    summary:     [mq]: 2019-02-12_18-10-04_r91+.diff
|
o  changeset:   91:88cca7c8f32e
|  user:        test <test@gmail.com>
|  date:        Tue Feb 12 18:09:49002019 +0100
|  summary:     some message
|
```

Question 1: What is the meaning of changeset 92. Is this comparable to a rewinded commit in git?

Question 2: What does *mq* mean in this context?

**Problem B: Timestamp that does not match with parent!**

```
o  changeset:   62:143401518e68
|  parent:      60:327ffdb4b8c3
|  user:        test <test@gmail.com>
|  date:        Fri Nov 16 21:19:00 2018 +0100
|  summary:     some message
|
| o  changeset:   61:b4a37ff37688
|/   user:        test <test@gmail.com>
|    date:        Fri Nov 16 16:00:00 2018 +0100
|    summary:     some message
|
o  changeset:   60:327ffdb4b8c3
|  user:        test <test@gmail.com>
|  date:        Fri Nov 16 18:10:00 2018 +0100
|  summary:     some message
|
```

Question 3: How do I have to interpret the timestamp of changeset 61? Should the timestamp of 61 be between the timestamps of changeset 60 and 62?

Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: As for the timestamps it is possible that changesets were re-ordered or that the date was entered explicitly during committing, which does not enforce any "order" for the timestamps of subsequent changesets.

Comment: What i still dont get: Even if the date has no real value, what the interpretation of the branch-like visual representation? Especially as the changeset 62 does not build upon changeset 61 but 60...

Comment: The graph drawn there is a representation of Mercurial's DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph). Every changeset has a number of parent changesets. (Zero for the initial changeset in a repo, one usually, two for merges.) A changeset may have zero or any higher amount of child changesets. In your case revision 60 was the parent for 61 and, separately, 62 as well. The way the graph is drawn may also be influenced (much like the decimal revision IDs) by the order the changesets were created in or pulled into the repo you are observing, I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem A: "mq"**

A1+A2: I *suppose*, it is commit (`hg commit --mq`), related to using [Mercurial Queues](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension) extension, which is separate long topic of queues|patches etc. And now you try to understand repo, which *used* MQ, with your Mercurial *without MQ* extension enabled (which is tricky task)

No, mq and `0aff2e92ec57` hasn't any relation with git's rewinded commit and serve [another role](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqTutorial) (I'm too lazy to repeat tutorial here)

**Problem B: Timestamp that does not match with parent!**

A3: As @ecm already noted, timestamps of changesets have near-zero value, because it can be changed|redefined